# How to connect my Nodejs Lambda to a Serverless Elasticache running memcached distribution

Tags: aws-lambda, memcached, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache, tls1.3

I have deployed Serverless Elasticache running Memcached Engine inside my VPC. I want my Nodejs Lambda inside my VPC to `GET/SET` values from this Elasticache. Since Serverless Elasticache comes with `in-transit` Encryption enabled by default, how can I connect my lambda to this TLS enable Elasticache? I was able to connect to my Elasticache from EC2 running inside same VPC through `openssl s_client -connect ELASTICACHE_ENDPOINT:PORT` command. I used `memcache-plus` NPM module to connect, but recieving connection error. Do my Lambda require `client_cert.pem` to access AWS managed Cache? If so how to include certs in my lambda?

This is my `memcache-plus` code:

```
const MemcachePlus = require('memcache-plus');
const client = new MemcachePlus({
   hosts: [process.env.ELASTICACHE_ENDPOINT],
   autodiscover: true,
   onNetError: function (err) {
     console.error(err);
   },
 });
```

How to add `TLS Certs` if required? Or is there any way without certificates?

*P.S All my Security Groups for Lambda, Elasticache are configured correctly & Lambda is in same private subnet as Elasticache*

I tried including `tls : {}` with no options inside memcache client initialisation, don't how to include certs inside lambda, if required.